# How to read/write a List<Date> to a Parcel?

Tags: android, date, serialization, parcelable, parcel

I have a class that implements `Parcelable`. What's the best way to read/write a `List` of `Date` objects to a `Parcel`?

This is how you can do it for a single `Date` object:

```
    date = new Date(parcel.readLong()); //read

    parcel.writeLong(date.getTime());   //write
```

But how to do it for a `List<Date>`?

I suppose the ham-fisted way of doing the write would be to loop through all `Date` objects and construct a `long[]`, like so:

```
long[] datesAsLongs = new long[dates.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++)
    datesAsLongs[i] = dates.get(i).getTime();
parcel.writeLongArray(datesAsLongs);
```

And to read, you could do:

```
dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
for (long dateAsLong : parcel.createLongArray())
    dates.add(new Date(dateAsLong));
```

But I was hoping there would be something better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Date is a Serializable object you should be able to use [`writeList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeList%28java.util.List%29):

```
List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
parcel.writeList(list);
```

ArrayList also implements Serializable so you might be able to use [`writeValue()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
List<Date> list = new ArrayList<Date>();
parcel.writeValue(list);
```

Worst case you can use [`writeSerializable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeSerializable%28java.io.Serializable%29)

Comment: Yes, I have considered this, but `List` does not implement `Serializable` (even though `ArrayList` does), so you would have to cast it. I don't want to do that, if possible. Not to mention that `writeSerializable()` has performance implications...

Comment: List is an interface, it cannot implement Serializable, your `List<Date>` object is really an ArrayList of Dates that has the List methods. I'm unclear on why you haven't used `writeList()`. By "Not to mention that writeSerializable() has performance implications..." I assume you've read the Parcel documentation, but did your read the selection on Untyped Containers? `readList()` and `writeList()` are the methods you want.

Comment: No, my list of `Date` objects is not guaranteed to be an `ArrayList`... The class it resides in has a public `setDates(List<Date> dates)` setter, so I cannot assume it will always be an `ArrayList`. That's why I purposely wrote `List<Date>` in the title of this question. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: I see. While _I_ may have been too short sighted to consider other types of List implementations here, the developers where not. I just tested `writeList()` and `readList()` with LinkedList, Stack, and Vector. I also took a look through the source code, these methods should work with _any_ class that implements List.

Comment: Cool, just had a look at the `writeList()` source myself, and you are correct in saying it will work with any `List` implementation. Using this method will still end up calling `writeSerializable()` for each `Date` object, though. Do you know if such generic serialization of `Date` objects would degrade performance? I doubt it would much, since a `Date` object is just a wrapper for a `long` primitive... (Thanks, I will leave this question open for a bit longer, but if no one else provides any input, I will accept your answer.)

Comment: "Do you know if such generic serialization of Date objects would degrade performance?" I did some simple tests and didn't notice a definitive difference... But considering the documentations warnings you should write a sticky note to double check for yourself in DDMS when you are done writing the app.